# Get TextField text property after keyboard done in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a TextField and want to listen to the event when the user finished typing and wants to go on. I neither want to call a function each time a user presses any key nor I want to add a submit button. The keyboard offers a 'done' button, so why don't use this. The only question which follows is how to listen to that specific event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`returnPress` should do what you want:

```
<TextField (returnPress)="returnPress()"
```

Comment: Do I have to pass an event as parameter or should I use `@ChildView` to access the text property?

Comment: You can use `[(ngModel)]="myProp"` to be able to get the content from `this.myProp`. Actually not sure, there might be a timing issue. You can try `<TextField #tf (returnPress)="returnPress(tf.value)" ` if the former doesn't work (I don't really know ionic)

Comment: Okay, that was easy :D Thank you.

Comment: To pass the value did not work, but getting the property from the model does.

Comment: I can't figure out why, but the value passed is an empty string all the time in that case.

Comment: empty string ... when passed what way? Can you please add the code to your question?

Comment: When doing `<TextField #tf (returnPress)="returnPress(tf.value)" [(ngModel)]="myProp">` in the template and `returnPress(txt: string) { console.log(txt); }` in the component, I got only an empty string.

Comment: but `this.myProp` does have the value? According to the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/text-field) it probably should be `"returnPress(tf.text)"` (`text` instead of `value`)

Comment: Using the model is the preferred way anyway.

Comment: Well, okay. Then I should do it this way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

With NativeScript 3 you can use the new `blur` event. That way you will not only call a function when the Enter key is pressed, but also when the user leaves the field by other means (tap a different field for instance).

See the API reference here https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_base_.textfield.html#blurevent

Example:

```
<TextField (blur)="userLeftTheField()">
```